# Saxparser syntax error

Tags: android, saxparser

I am trying to parse a HTML/XML UTF-8 file with saxparser but i am getting the following parse error:

```
ERROR/ParseError:(26854): org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 62: syntax error
```

Here is the XML example:

I want to parse the data in the TD elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-             strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="nl" lang="nl">
<TABLE class=personaltable cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
 <TBODY>
  <TR class=alternativerow>
   <TD>Nieuw beltegoed:</TD>
   <TD>€ 1,00</TD></TR>
  <TR>
   <TD>Tegoed vorige periode: 
   <TD>€ 2,00</TD></TD></TR>
  <TR class=alternativerow>
   <TD>Tegoed tot 09-11-2011: 
   <TD>€ 10,00</TD></TD></TR>
  <TR>
   <TD>
   <TD height=25></TD>
  <TR class=alternativerow>
   <TD>Verbruik sinds nieuw tegoed:</TD>
   <TD>€ 0,33</TD></TR>
  <TR>
   <TD>Ongebruikt tegoed:</TD>
   <TD>€ 12,00</TD></TR>
  <TR class=alternativerow>
   <TD class=f-Orange>Verbruik boven bundel:</TD>
   <TD class=f-Orange>€ 0,00</TD></TR>
  <TR>
   <TD>Verbruik dat niet in de bundel zit*:</TD>
   <TD>€ 0,00</TD></TR>
 </TBODY>
</TABLE>
</html>
```

Can somebody please help?

Could also someone check the code, as this is my first code for the saxparser.

Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
try{    
                SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance(); 
                SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser(); 
                XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader(); 

                ExampleHandler myExampleHandler = new ExampleHandler();
                xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);

                // Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler )  
                xr.parse(new InputSource(getAssets().open("File parse.htm")));

                ParsedExampleDataSet parsedExampleDataSet = myExampleHandler.getParsedData();

                tv.setText("");
                tv.setText(parsedExampleDataSet.toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                /* Display any Error to the GUI. */
                tv.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                Log.e("ParseError: ", "WeatherQueryError", e);
            }
```

The handler itself:

```
 private boolean in_TABLE = false;
    private boolean in_TBODY = false;
    private boolean in_TR = false;
    private boolean in_TD = false;

    private ParsedExampleDataSet myParsedExampleDataSet = new ParsedExampleDataSet();

    // ===========================================================
    // Getter & Setter
    // ===========================================================

    public ParsedExampleDataSet getParsedData() {
            return this.myParsedExampleDataSet;
    }

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods
    // ===========================================================
    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
            this.myParsedExampleDataSet = new ParsedExampleDataSet();
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
            // Nothing to do
    }

    /** Gets be called on opening tags like: 
     * <tag> 
     * Can provide attribute(s), when xml was like:
     * <tag attribute="attributeValue">*/
    @Override
    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
                    String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
            if (localName.equals("TABLE class=personaltable cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0")) {
                    this.in_TABLE = true;
            }else if (localName.equals("TBODY")) {
                    this.in_TBODY = true;
            }else if (localName.equals("TR class=alternativerow")) {
                    this.in_TR = true;
            }else if (localName.equals("TD")) {
                    // Extract an Attribute
                    String attrValue = atts.getValue("TD");
                    int i = Integer.parseInt(attrValue);
                    myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedInt(i);
            }
    }

    /** Gets be called on closing tags like: 
     * </tag> */
    @Override
    public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName)
                    throws SAXException {
            if (localName.equals("TABLE class=personaltable cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0")) {
                    this.in_TABLE = false;
            }else if (localName.equals("TBODY")) {
                    this.in_TBODY = false;
            }else if (localName.equals("TR class=alternativerow")) {
                    this.in_TR = false;
            }else if (localName.equals("TD")) {
                    // Nothing to do here
            }
    }

    /** Gets be called on the following structure: 
     * <tag>characters</tag> */
    @Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
            if(this.in_TD){
            myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedString(new String(ch, start, length));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple Answer

Your XML is not well-formed for the following reasons:

- You have unquoted attributes. All attribute values must be quoted.
- You have unclosed `TD` and `TR` elements. All elements must be closed (i.e. must have a matching end tag).

You need to fix those errors before continuing.

#### Teach-a-man-to-fish Answer

You need to invest (your time) in an XML tool that produces better error messages. Dropping your document into any decent well-formedness validator would have revealed these issues immediately.

Comment: Hi lwburk,
This is an external page which i retrieve by HTTPClient, the TD and TR elements are all closed as far as i can see.
Please suggest how to fix this.
Thx

Comment: Line 12 of the example above opens `<TR><TD>`; these are never closed. If you can't control the input, and it's not XML, then you can't treat it as XML. The specification requires processors to reject documents that aren't well-formed.

Comment: Hi lwburk,
I edited the xml and put in the startline, can it be parsed with saxparser anyhow?